# Manually opening an EntityConnection to SQLite database causes ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

For integration testing purposes I'd like to manually create and open an EntityConnection in the test fixture set up. This fails with the following exception when calling the Open() method:

*System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException : A null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.*

I'm using the same connection string which is also used when EF takes care about connection opening. If I run the same test suite with automatic connection handling by EF it works.

```
...
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void FixtureSetUp()
{
    // Setup database 
    // Setup data access
    ... 
    var ec = new EntityConnection([ConnectionString]);
    ec.StoreConnection.Open(); --> WORKS!!
    ec.Open(); -> Throws
}
...
```

The connection string looks like the following:

```
metadata=res://*/Test.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Test.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Test.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string="data source=C:\Test\tmp4C80.tmp;read only=False;pooling=False;failifmissing=True;synchronous=Full;datetimekind=Utc;enlist=True;setdefaults=False;datetimeformat=ISO8601;journal mode=Off;cache size=4194304"
```

The app.config for the NUnit assembly is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework"
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"
                      type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <!-- Register protable database data providers -->
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                 description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Beside NUnit for testing, I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and System.Data.SQLite 1.0.94.0.

Edit: The strange thing is that opening the store connection of the provided entity connection manually works...

Comment: Have you tried: provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6 in the EF connection string?

Comment: Yes, since I did not configure a provider with the name System.Data.SQLite.EF6 in my app.config I get the exception:
System.ArgumentException : The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Comment: I think it's an Entity Framework configuration or assembly resolving problem which is not related to SQLite, maybe some EF experts can jump in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I used the *EntityConnection* from *System.Data.Entity* instead of the *EntityFramework* assembly.